# Is it possible to mask CALayer in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, calayer, masking

I'm trying to mask CALayer with a bitmap image.
And I failed masking CALayer. My code is:

```
// 'PreloadViewController layerWithImageNamed' create a layer and set it's contents as specified UIImage.
CALayer* title = [PreloadViewController layerWithImageNamed:@"pinkhug_txt.png"];
 [[[self view] layer] addSublayer:title];

 CALayer* title_mask = [PreloadViewController layerWithImageNamed:@"hug_mask.png"];
 [title setMask:title_mask];
```

The Apple reference says ["CALayer in iPhone does not support mask property"](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/LayerStyleProperties/LayerStyleProperties.html). 
But there is [a postings about this on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2267676/masking-a-calayer-iphone).
Is it possible? Or what's wrong with my code?

Comment: I added 'iphone' tag. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my fault and resolved now. I used an image without alpha channel. Unlike traditional masking techniques, CALayer uses mask image's alpha channel as mask data.