# Create a hole in CALayer iOS

Tags: ios, calayer, masking

I have a UIImage in the view. I need to create a layer on top of it with a transparent
 hole in it so that I can view only a part of the image and everything else will be the color of the layer. I tried varying masking options but my layer becomes fully transparent or the mask takes the color of the layer. I want the inverse of it. The mask rectangle should be transparent while the entire layer remain opaque.

Any advice ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I cut a notch out of a CALayer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7835297/how-do-i-cut-a-notch-out-of-a-calayer)